# How to make chrome download multiple files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, google-chrome

I am playing Minecraft Java with mods and recently I've run into a problem where I can't download all of my mods because of the chrome safe browsing, I could sit down and download them all but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it, because I'm bad at this here is a [screenshot of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se7qF.png). If anyone knows how to keep all of them at once that would be great!

--tysm, Ancient Bison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Chrome support](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10158080?hl=en#:%7E:text=Disable%20Safe%20Browsing%20in%20Chrome%201%20Click%20the,and%20your%20device%20from%20dangerous%20sites%29.%20See%20More.),

> 1. Click the **Chrome menu** at the top right > **Settings.**
> 2. Scroll down and click **Advanced.**
> 3. Click **Sync and Google services.**
> 4. Use the slider to turn off **Safe Browsing.**

This is the only way I am aware of to be able to stop this block from happening.